# Return 'junk value' that is const

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, return, constants

```
float& Matrix_Row::get(const unsigned int &row_indx, const unsigned int &column_indx){
    Matrix_Column* temp = head;

    while(temp){
        if(temp->row_indx == row_indx){
            return temp->get(column_indx);
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // add default return not found
}
```

Is there any way to return 0 without having to create specific variable... like is there a sort of NULL value that I can return.

So I could create a 'NOT-FOUND' const value in the original class and then when calling this function I just add that value as a parameter, then if its not found i just return that parameter value; however, I don't really want to do this because it could clash with the data variable value. example: I could return -1 but then in actuality the data value is -1 and then I won't be able to distinguish if it was a success or failure.

Thank You

Comment: No. Return something like `std::optional` or a pointer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a null reference.

Comment: Or don't return anything, throw an exception for the not found case.

Comment: `struct not_found{};` and `throw not_found{};`.  Or maybe `static float not_found;` and `not_found = std::nanf(""); return not_found;`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are returning by reference. Returning by reference tells any user of this method that it will always return a valid value. Obviously, you are violating this rule by trying to return "NOT-FOUND", indicating there is no valid value. References are merely pointers that can never be null. Pointers just point to other existing variables, but they can be null; not pointing to anything. null is usually a good indicator to use for "NOT-FOUND".

A simple rule to follow that fits both parameters and return values:

- Use a reference if it cannot be null
- Use a pointer if it could be null

So rewrite your method like this instead:

```
float* Matrix_Row::get(const unsigned int &row_indx, const unsigned int &column_indx){
    Matrix_Column* temp = head;

    while(temp){
        if(temp->row_indx == row_indx){
            return temp->get(column_indx);
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    // add default return not found
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then the calling code can check the return value for nullptr as its "NOT-FOUND" indicator. Also I'm not sure what `return temp->get(column_indx);` is returning, but you'll probably need to modify that as well to make sure it is returning a `float*`. If it's returning a reference, then you could do `return &temp->get(column_indx);` to support the change above

Answer (score -1):

return -> pair<bool,float>

this way I can check if a value was found, I can also add any default float value if not found.

not the best solution because it will take more memory than using optional

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).